# do something after SVN update

Tags: linux, svn, unix

Is there anything possible do something after SVN update process?.

I need to execute some shell script after the SVN update process. Please help me how to do that?.

SVN Version: 1.6.17

Comment: Unix / windows ? What's the reason for those needed callings?

Comment: Yes, It's Unix* flavour. I'm using now Fedora.

Comment: You didn't answer the question: What you like to achieve ?

Comment: Ok.. This is my requirement. Actually now i'm working in limited user account (F16). ex: user: mrblack. The problem is when i'm execute the command "svn update", it's working fine. But the updated/downloaded files owner name is changed to ROOT. Bcz, my actual repository is under ROOT user. So, i need to execute the "chown" command after the each svn update. ???

Comment: Sounds like you are accessing via file:/// protocol ? If so your permissions in the repository is wrong. How did you created the repository ?

Comment: NO.. Actually, many people working with that repository under root user. But only one person is working with limited user.

Comment: You didn't answer the questions: access via file?, How did you created the repository ? Furthermore working as root is in general the wrong way...in particular under unix...root is for adminstrative task but not for general work...

Comment: Hey!! I already answered.. "NO". I'm not using file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7837/discussion-between-mr-black-and-khmarbaise)

Comment: You should give the honor to the people who have helped you by upvoting the answers etc.

Comment: Oh!!!.. Sorry, I missed that.. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the client side you can call svn client via a shell/batch script and run your needed commands after that but from SVN side there is nothing you can use for that.

After discussion on the chat the problem was the permission problem in configuration of Apache under Fedora and not a problem of SVN.

Comment: Thanks @khmarbaise. Yes, I understood. Your suggestion is working only with the following scenario. http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/08BW

Answer (score 0):

Use [phing](http://www.phing.info/trac/).

1. use the svn update task
2. use the exec task to run the scripts

Comment: Thanks @markus. It's very nice. Can you please give me some example to do this?. Bcz, I'm new for this.